# Can I use SIPS to reduce the size of PNG files by reducing the number of palette colors?

Tags: command-line, color, image-processing, sips

I need to shrink [PNG](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter08.html) files like the ones generated as the default macOS screenshot. [SIPS](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sips.1.html) was my first stop since it's faster than any other solution but I haven't quite been able to find the right command.

This is my starting point to reformat to PNG:

```
/usr/bin/sips -s format png  "$f" --out "${f%.*}.png"
```

Which options are needed?

```
--setProperty bitsPerSample
```

Bits/sample looks promising but I'm not sure what to enter here.
 
Does 32 mean 32 colors in this context, for example?

Can I use SIPS to quickly reduce the number of colors to shrink file size?

Comment: bitsPerSample is referring to the [color depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth) of the image.

Comment: So, if I reduced the color depth, the PNG should shrink, right? Based on the link you sent, I should set this to `--setProperty bitsPerSample 4` for 16 colors per bit or `--setProperty bitsPerSample 8` for 256, shouldn't I?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, bitsPerSample is a read-only property and you cannot modify it through sips. You can use ImageMagick instead. Consult https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613105/uncommon-png-file-ios-display for more info. Hope this helps. Recently encounter a similar thing.